# Function don't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm working with plugin [Portfilter](https://github.com/geedmo/portfilter). It's work with select tag in IE, FF but not in Chrome. Anyone know what's wrong?

JS

```
$('select#car_value').change(function(){
  $.fn.portfilter(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="car_value">
    <option value="abarth" data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="abarth">Abarth</option>
</select>
```

ps. I have over 30 option tag, this one is only for example

---

**[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xPqOVg)**

Comment: what does it say on debug console?

Comment: @Taha Paksu in fact nothing, I have no errors at all. It works in Firefox. Even in IE. I don't know what wrong. I'm using this in wordpress if it's important

Comment: If you remove the js part, only leaving data-toggle="portfilter" on the options, does it work?

Comment: @Taha Paksu no, it's not working

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the javascript part to:

```
$('select#car_value').change(function(){
  $(":selected", this).portfilter('filter');
});
```

Which was also contained in the plugin initialization part, and it worked.

Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqWROK

Comment: Yesss! Work like it should. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your change function is working fine. The issue seems to be with the $.fn.portfilter function. Do you have this library included correctly? It seems to show an error like shown below in the snippet when I copy all your code form the codepen, but the error is fixed when you add the portfilter js file from https://github.com/geedmo/portfilter. I think your issue is just that you did not add the necessary portfilter tags.

```js
$('select#car_value').change(function(){
  alert("change")
  $.fn.portfilter(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
});
```

```css
.info-text h4+p {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #ed1c24;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.car-item, .news-item, .testimonials-item {
    width: calc(33% - 20px);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="all">all</li>
<li data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="bmw">bmw</li>
<li data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="mercedes">mercedes</li>
</ul>

<select id="car_value">
<option data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="all">all</option>
<option data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="bmw">bmw</option>
<option data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="mercedes">mercedes</option>
</select>

<div class="realizations-flex-row filter-row">  
    
    <div class="car car-item info-text" data-tag="">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l03dt748QdA" target="_blank">
            <div class="car-background" style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/l03dt748QdA/maxresdefault.jpg');">
                <i class="flaticon-play-button"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
        <h2>Honda Civic Type R</h2>
        <h4>2007 r.</h4>
        <p>11.450 euro</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="car car-item info-text" data-tag="">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3M6CiDlPw4U" target="_blank">
            <div class="car-background" style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/3M6CiDlPw4U/maxresdefault.jpg');">
                <i class="flaticon-play-button"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
        <h2>Mitsubishi Outlander 2.0</h2>
        <h4>2006 r.</h4>
        <p>8.500 euro</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="car car-item info-text" data-tag="">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_n8qfhunXbU" target="_blank">
            <div class="car-background" style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/_n8qfhunXbU/maxresdefault.jpg');">
                <i class="flaticon-play-button"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
        <h2>Opel Zafira 1.8 Benzyna</h2>
        <h4>2008 r.</h4>
        <p>8.750 euro</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="car car-item info-text" data-tag="mercedes">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OVM_GihMRk" target="_blank">
            <div class="car-background" style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/4OVM_GihMRk/maxresdefault.jpg');">
                <i class="flaticon-play-button"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
        <h2>Mercedes-Benz S350</h2>
        <h4>2012 r.</h4>
        <p>35.800 euro</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="car car-item info-text" data-tag="mercedes">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRMn5RypJbk" target="_blank">
            <div class="car-background" style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/nRMn5RypJbk/maxresdefault.jpg');">
                <i class="flaticon-play-button"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
        <h2>Mercedes-Benz 123</h2>
        <h4>1981 r.</h4>
        <p>5.800 euro</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="car car-item info-text" data-tag="bmw">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82LUEyq4Nvc" target="_blank">
            <div class="car-background" style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/82LUEyq4Nvc/maxresdefault.jpg');">
                <i class="flaticon-play-button"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
        <h2>BMW 520d</h2>
        <h4>2013 r.</h4>
        <p>36.450 euro</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think I added all neccessary tags. I don't know what's wrong. But @Taha Paksu posted answer that works for me

Comment: I see his answer now. Yep looks like the "$.fn.portfilter(this.options[this.selectedIndex])" command was just the wrong syntax to use. Good deal.

Answer (score 0):

you have only `one option value` value thats why `change event no work` after create two or more option

its work

```js
$('select#car_value').change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="car_value">
    <option value="abarth" data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="abarth">Abarth</option>
    <option value="abarth" data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="abarth">Abarth</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have over 30 options so no, it's not working for me. This one is only for example

Comment: what was the problem

Comment: check this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xPqOVg It's working on FF, IE but no in chrome. If you click on list element, everything works great. But when I want do the same with select it's not working (only in chrome)